# How to change different torch model last layer for finetuning in a unified way?

Tags: pytorch, torchvision

I have a `torch model` that receive a pretrained model and alter the last `module` of pretrained model for finetuning. But a realistic situation is the last module of these pretrained model have different name, for instance, `torchvision.models.resnet*()` is `fc`, `timm.models.vit*()` is `head`, some other may contain several output layer comprising the last   module.

What I want is that I can alter these different layers in a unified way. Such as

```py
last_model = get_last_module(pretrained_model)
last_model = nn.Sequential(...)
```

.
But in this way, the `pretrained_model` do not changed at all.

For example, what I do in a stupid way:

```
    def __init__(self, base_encoder, pred_dim=512):
        """
        dim: feature dimension (default: 2048)
        pred_dim: hidden dimension of the predictor (default: 512)
        """
        super().__init__()

        # create the encoder
        # num_classes is the output fc dimension, zero-initialize last BNs
        self.encoder = base_encoder
        if isinstance(self.encoder, torchvision.models.ResNet):
            dim = self.encoder.fc.out_features
            # build a 3-layer projector
            prev_dim = self.encoder.fc.in_features
            self.encoder.fc = nn.Sequential(
                nn.Linear(prev_dim, prev_dim, bias=False),
                nn.BatchNorm1d(prev_dim),
                nn.ReLU(inplace=True),  # first layer
                nn.Linear(prev_dim, prev_dim, bias=False),
                nn.BatchNorm1d(prev_dim),
                nn.ReLU(inplace=True),  # second layer
                # nn.Linear(prev_dim, dim),
                self.encoder.fc,
                nn.BatchNorm1d(dim, affine=False),
            )  # output layer
            self.encoder.fc[
                6
            ].bias.requires_grad = False  # hack: not use bias as it is followed by BN

        elif isinstance(self.encoder, timm.models.VisionTransformer):
            dim = self.encoder.head.out_features
            # build a 3-layer projector
            prev_dim = self.encoder.head.in_features
            self.encoder.head = nn.Sequential(
                nn.Linear(prev_dim, prev_dim, bias=False),
                nn.BatchNorm1d(prev_dim),
                nn.ReLU(inplace=True),  # first layer
                nn.Linear(prev_dim, prev_dim, bias=False),
                nn.BatchNorm1d(prev_dim),
                nn.ReLU(inplace=True),  # second layer
                # nn.Linear(prev_dim, dim),
                self.encoder.head,
                nn.BatchNorm1d(dim, affine=False),
            )  # output layer
            self.encoder.head[
                6
            ].bias.requires_grad = False  # hack: not use bias as it is followed by BN

            # build a 2-layer predictor
        self.predictor = nn.Sequential(
            nn.Linear(dim, pred_dim, bias=False),
            nn.BatchNorm1d(pred_dim),
            nn.ReLU(inplace=True),  # hidden layer
            nn.Linear(pred_dim, dim),
        )
```

Answer (score 1):

How about using children?

```
pretrained_model_except_last_layer = list(pretrained_model.children())[:-1]
new_model = nn.Sequential(*pretrained_model_except_last_layer, your_new_classfier)
```

Comment: It's an elegant choice to do something excluding the last layer. But my finetuning implementation needs to reuse the last layer in `your_new_classifier`, so the last module cannot be simply exclued. I prefer a modification in place. Meanwhile, for some models, there are not only one branch such as `yolo`.